# What steps to add a user to a system without using useradd/adduser?

Tags: users, useradd

I was browsing through some Linux questions and saw this interesting question.

*What steps to add a user to a system without using `useradd`/`adduser`?*

The one possible way that comes to my mind is,

- Add an entry for the user in `/etc/passwd` file.
- Add an entry for the group in `/etc/group` file.
- Create the home directory for the added user.
- Set the new user password using the `passwd` command.

I tested the above approach and it worked fine.

Is this the only possible way or is there any other work around to achieve this?

Comment: Good question, But where would this be useful?

Comment: @Networker, from the same link I posted in the answer, I found this information as well. *It is sometimes necessary to create dummy accounts that are not used by people. For example, to set up an anonymous FTP server*.

Comment: @Networker, may be practical cases it might be useless. However, still it is useful in some interview questions which is where I originally got this question. http://serverfault.com/a/225954

Comment: thanks for this explanation, and your answer is useful indeed, I will give it a try in the future.

Comment: I think the text quoted from the link is just there to make the point that setting a password may not be a good idea for dummy accounts: when creating a dummy account, it's still generally easier to use `useradd` (not necessarily `adduser`, which automatically does a bunch of stuff which probably isn't needed for dummy users). That said, it's still nice to know what's being done internally, because that can help with various administrative tasks.

Comment: In debian/Ubuntu and Kubuntu Users with `UID` less than `1000` doesn't show in the list of users in login page (Such as root user with UID=0). This can't help you to use `adduser` command and  then change the `UID` by `usermod -u UID USER` instead of using an abnormal way to add a dummy user?

Comment: I used this QA recently when dealing with Gentoo Prefix on Android [where `sys-apps/shadow` can't be currently installed due to a bug](https://bugs.gentoo.org/543744) so in order to build the `man-pages` package I had to resort to the manual creation of the `man` user.

Comment: @Networker : here a use case: WSL Ubuntu on Win10 refuses to work, complains about lock files  and continues refusing to work after removing said files (working as root). I bet it's related to the Win10 version, but I can't update right now. So, that's a case where I would use this method.

Comment: @Networker Here's my use case. For some reason, I just want to experience what it was like in the good old UNIX days before they had fancy newfangled tools like `adduser`. IDK, my grandpa used to tell the whole "walked to school uphill both ways" story, but for some reason, I never found a use case for that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The possible way to add a user is more or less similar to what I had put in the question. I got this approach from [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/adduser.html).

To create a new account manually, follow these steps:

Edit `/etc/passwd` with `vipw` and add a new line for the new account. Be careful with the syntax. Do not edit directly with an editor. `vipw` locks the file so that other commands won't try to update it simultaneously. You should make the password field be `*', so that it is impossible to log in.

Similarly, edit `/etc/group` with `vigr` if you need to create a new group as well.

Create the home directory of the user with `mkdir`.

Copy the files from `/etc/skel` to the new home directory.

Fix ownerships and permissions with `chown` and `chmod`. The `-R` option is most useful. The correct permissions vary a little from one site to another, but usually the following commands do the right thing:

- `cd /home/newusername`
- `chown -R username:group .`
- `chmod -R go=u,go-w .`
- `chmod go= .`

Set the password with `passwd`.

After you set the password in the last step, the account will work. You shouldn't set it until everything else has been done, otherwise the user may inadvertently log in while you're still copying the files.